# Create an image and colored ir?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

how can I create an image and how can I colored it pixel by pixel using hexadecimal code of colors?

For ex. I wanna create a 100x100 pixel image and I wanto to 1x1 area's color is '$002125',2x2 area's color is '$125487'.... How can I do it?

Thank you for your answers..

Comment: Create a `TBitmap` object, set its `PixelFormat` property to `pf24bit`, set its width & height, then use its `Canvas.Pixels` property. You an find more detail in Delphi's offline help.

Comment: can you write an example how can ı use it.I m new in delphi.

Comment: @Jay, don't use `Canvas.Pixels`, it's very inefficient (slow) method for pixel manipulation. Kerem, could you make an example picture of what do you mean ?

Comment: for example I create a 100x100 pixel image and then I color it pixel by pixel.first pixel has '$012365' color and etc..

Comment: I saw scanline in google.what is this? Can ı use it for my project?

Comment: @TLama: That's true, but it's the easiest one since OP seems new at this. Shoving the scan line method might be to much for starters.

Comment: I dont know anything about scanline or what.İf u can write an example then ı can get some ıdea and ı can write my code.

Comment: By what do you want to color those pixels ?

Comment: Yeah, but you wanted to color each pixel with different color. Consider that you have 16777215 colors and 100px wide image. How do you want to color each of these pixels ? Or you want to have a function which will have color and position where will this color will be placed in the image as parameters ? If the second case, then the `Canvas.Pixels` will be enough.

Comment: ok what may it size? 1600x1600 or what for my project.and ı create an bitmap image but its has big size too.can ı use jpeg or bmp?

Comment: Where does the pixel data come from? In what form is it stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made a simple sample for you. Using Canvas.Pixels not Scanline. Scanline is faster though but for start I think it suits just fine. The colors are randomly generated, so you just need to replace this part of the code.

```
    procedure TForm1.GenerateImageWithRandomColors;
    var
      Bitmap: TBitmap;
      I, J: Integer;
      ColorHEX: string;

    begin
      Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
      Randomize;

      try
        Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
        Bitmap.Width := 100;
        Bitmap.Height := 100;

        for I := 0 to Pred(Bitmap.Width) do
        begin
          for J := 0 to Pred(Bitmap.Height) do
          begin
            Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, J] := RGB(Random(256),
               Random(256),
               Random(256));

            // get the HEX value of color and do something with it
            ColorHEX := ColorToHex(Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, J]);
          end;
        end;

        Bitmap.SaveToFile('test.bmp');
      finally
        Bitmap.Free;
      end;
    end;

function TForm1.ColorToHex(Color : TColor): string;
begin
  Result :=
     IntToHex(GetRValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetGValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetBValue(Color), 2);
end;
```

Comment: What kind of file is created with Bitmap.SaveToFile('test.jpg')

Comment: If I remember correctly, including JPEG in the uses clause does something, but it might be to the TGraphic class, not TBitmap. So my guess is that you're right, and it will write a BMP file named "test.jpg"

Comment: well its work fine thank you.but now,how can ı get the hex values of colors pixel by pixel as string?

Comment: yes. for example first I gave the color for canvas....[1,1]:='$00124F'.and then ı want to read reversly $00124F.how can ı do it? thank you agaın.

Comment: ok I solve it and I get the hex code.no problem.well my last question.for example what size of pic.(width x height) I chosed for 1 billion pixel? possible?

Comment: :D well what is the maximum size that ı can use this procedure? ı can write it part by part.ı tried now 20000x20000 but program locked :D

Comment: Kerem, what size do you *think* you should choose to get a billion pixels? Images are rectangular. Choose a width, do basic division, and you'll have the height. Or take the square root to get height and width together. If your computer doesn't let you create an image that big, then choose something smaller, and use several pieces.

Comment: thank your answer Rob Kennedy. ı have 1 billion pixel :D if is impossible ı will write it part by part. :D ı want to learn the max. size picture that ı use with this procedure.

Comment: or ı have 1 billion hex value. so is it mean 1 billion pixel am ı righr?

Comment: I think you may want to use threads too if you generating images so big :)

Comment: hmm ok. thank you all answers. my problem is solved.thank you agaın :D

Comment: yes but I have no 15 repoputıon.ı did but it didnt. sorry but last questıon. now my image file so big. how can I solve it. can ı convert it to jpeg or other formet?

Comment: You don't need any reputation to accept an answer. You also don't need any to ask questions in new posts. Please make a new post and ask your question there. Please remember to search previous answers before you ask, too.